# rails polymorphic_url destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some polymorphic_urls which are working ok for actions like new, edit, index, but I need it to destroy action too. Now url's are written like

```
polymorphic_url [:admin, item], action: :edit, routing_type: :path
```

I didn't see in docs anything related to destroy action, if there are possibility to call it somehow?

Comment: Have you tried a `method: :delete`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `:method => :delete` to the show path/url when you use it in link_to.  The `destroy` url and `show` url (as well as `update`) are all the same url, just different methods (respectively :delete, :get, :patch) in the request.

The method will show up in the a tag when you use link to.

```
=link_to polymorphic_url([...], options), :method => :delete
```